# Problem with matrices

Tags: matrices

Got one problem here where I don't really get what is being asked of me to do:
"Show all matrices $A \in M_{22}(\mathbb R)$, for which following applies: $A\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}A$"

Hope someone can explain

Comment: It's asking which matrices commute with the given matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to look for a matrices 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
 such that
$$A\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}A$$
which's equivalent to
$$(a=d)\land (c=0)$$